# Determine if view is hidden or not and change button state programmatically

Tags: ios, uiview, uibutton, visibility

I have three views and three buttons each button toggles the view (hidden = yes/no)

```
- (IBAction)switchOne:(id)sender {        
    [_firstPage setHidden:NO];
    [_secondPage setHidden:YES];
    [_thirdPage setHidden:YES];
}

- (IBAction)switchTwo:(id)sender {        
    [_firstPage setHidden:YES];
    [_secondPage setHidden:NO];
    [_thirdPage setHidden:YES];        
}

- (IBAction)switchThree:(id)sender {        
    [_firstPage setHidden:YES];
    [_secondPage setHidden:YES];
    [_thirdPage setHidden:NO];
}
```

I want to set the background of the button depending if the view is hidden or not.

I have tried this but without results:

```
if (_firstPage.hidden == NO)
{
    UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"currentPage.png"];
    [_pageOneButton setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.view addSubview:_pageOneButton];

} else if (_firstPage.hidden == YES) {
    [_pageOneButton setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

The `_pageOneButton` keeps the background even with the view hidden.

I leave an image of the menu as is now:

[image: menu-active]

The point is: when Página 2 is active (hidden == NO) the Página 1 button should be without the background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To few details here, but in the meantime you could play a bit with the following suggestions.

First, move your

```
[self.view addSubview:_pageOneButton];
```

outside the method. For example, in `viewDidLoad` method you add that button to a `superview`.

Then you can control its state (through a reference to it, as you did) like

```
// set the image
[_pageOneButton setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];

// remove the image
[_pageOneButton setImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: I have the if statement in the `viewDidLoad` method, should I move it to the `-(IBAction)`method and just leave the `[self.view addSubview:_pageOneButton];` in `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: I have added a bunch of if statements in each button to check if the view is hidden or not and that does the trick. @flexaddicted thank you very much! You have saved me!